# List the PATH's dirs where current user has permission to write?

Tags: grep, path

Can I extract from `PATH` only the directories where I (current user) have permissions to write?

I can imagine I'd need something like `echo $PATH | grep...` but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Split `$PATH` up on colons, by changing `IFS` to [split fields on colons](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) during [word expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06), and check whether you can write to each component with [the `-w` test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

```
(IFS=:; for p in $PATH; do [ -w "$p" ] && printf '%s\n' "$p"; done)
```

This will ignore empty entries (which represent [the current directory](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03)) and will give incorrect results for entries containing globbing characters (as pointed out by Uncle Billy). To handle both, use

```
sh -fc 'IFS=:; for p in $PATH""; do [ -w "${p:-.}" ] && printf "%s\n" "$p"; done'
```

Comment: I hope that nobody is going to use that for any "security" purposes, because its easily tricked by empty path entries (= current directory) and entries which looks like globs. (e.g. `/path/to/b[i]n` where that will check for `/path/to/bin`, but programs will be run from `/path/to/b[i]n`)

Comment: Easy enough to fix, though, I think: instead of `( … )` use something like `sh -fc ' … '`

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh` (where `$PATH` is tied to the `$path` array):

```
writable_path_components=( $^path(N-/e['[[ -w $REPLY ]]']) )
```

Will store in the `writable_path_components` array the `$PATH` components that are directories (determined after symlink resolution) and writable by the current user.

Empty elements are discarded. Having empty elements or any relative path for that matters in `$PATH` is strongly discouraged.

If `$PATH` contains relative paths, that means that while some of them might be writable now, they may no longer be once you cd elsewhere.

To sanitise `$PATH` and remove all relative paths as well as duplicates, you can do:

```
typeset -U path=( ${(M)path:#/*} )
```

Setting the `U` attribute on `$path` (which here remains tied to `$PATH`), means `$PATH` elements will remain unique.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I tested now and I get `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`

Comment: @João, your error message indicates you're using bash, not zsh.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it in `xonsh`

```
import os;[p for p in $PATH if os.access(p, os.W_OK)]
```

returns a list of paths that are writable.